# Why do all but the first row in a table show up as '#' when you call .all in rails console?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, model

I'm learning about models and databases in rails and when I create a table I can call `.all`on the model and get a empty array, but if I create multiple rows and I call `.all` I get an array where only the first row shows actual values and the rest are `#`.

Why doesnt the console display all the row values and if it doesn't how can I see all the values of the rows without calling `.find` on each one?

> irb(main):001:0> Todo.all
>
> Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" 
>   `[#<Todo id: 1, todo_item: "pick up milk", created_at: "2014-07-27 15:45:11", updated_at: 
>   "2014-07-27 15:45:11">, #, #]`
>
> irb(main):001:0> Todo.all.second
>
> Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos"

```
#<Todo id: 2, todo_item: "Pay internet bill", created_at: "2014-07-27 15:47:42", updated_at: "2014-07-27 15:47:42">
```

Comment: can you show the actual output here?

Comment: Try `.inspect` (or iterating over them)...

Comment: Thanks, I added output to description, inspect just shows me the Keys not the whole hash for each row

Comment: as a related side note; when I was trying to copy in the code to the description it kept collapsing it to an array with three hashes '[#,#,#]' Is collapsing hashes like this common?

Comment: What's the result of `Todo.all.second`?

Comment: added Todo.all.second output to description, sorry about the formatting it keeps collapsing my Hashes if i do it in a blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a feature of the console, shortening the output to show you the attributes of the model without filling the output space. If you need to see the actual attributes try collect for the contents you want to see:

```
TODO.all.collect{|x| x.todo_item}
```

or for the whole object...

```
 TODO.all.collect{|x| x.inspect}
```

A good approach is to write a custom to_s method with the content you most commonly want to see and use that. In your model...

```
def to_s
  "TODO: #{id} - #{todo_item}"
end
```

and use it like this:

```
TODO.all.collect{|x| x.to_s}
```

the upshot of the custom to_s is that it will also be used by a lot of debugging tools and by ruby string injections.